# Entity Framework - stored procedure call for record that contains nested json object: how to handle deserialize

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Environment:

- `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.7" />`
- SQL Server 2016
- .NET Core 3.1

Database table:

```
Id (Primary key)  
Settings (nvarchar(max) contains the nested json)  
DateCreated datetime  
DateModified datetime
```

I'm using the following EF dynamic call in c#:

```
return Context.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw($"EXEC {spName}").ToList();
```

C# object to deserialize to:

```
public class UserSetting
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public MyClass SettingData { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Errors I ran into:

> MyClass needs to be Keyless

When I fix that I get another error:

> There is no relationship between UserSetting and MyClass

Is it possible for Entity Framework to automatically deserialize `MyClass` type for property `SettingData` in `UserSetting` class?

**Update**

```
{
  "MyClass": {
    "MyProperty": "Hello World"
  }
}
```

[image]

**Update 2**
I'm testing update database table for only the SettingData property, is the following snippet correct for passing to SQL Server stored procedure? Because I'm getting error

```
new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@settingData", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = userSettingToUpdate.SettingData
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)" let you map database fields to object and vise versa :

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<UserSetting>()
    .Property(e => e.SettingData )
    .HasConversion(
                v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }),
                v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(v, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }));
```

Comment: I updated my OP to show my results based on your answer and I'm getting null value for MyProperty. Is my JSON correct?

Comment: The JSON you provided produce two class which is incorrect for defined conversation, you should change your Json or update MyClass definition to handle it, use https://json2csharp.com to know what your JSON produce.

Comment: Thank you and nice link to json2csharp never knew about it.

Comment: I added an Update2 to OP, I'm trying to only update the SettingData property in UserSetting. I'm not sure I'm passing the parameter correctly. I tried userToUpdate and userToUpdate.SettingData and got the following error